# Setting up SDL2 with Visual Studio 2015 and I run the program and it broken up

Tags: sdl-2, visual-studio-2015

I set up the SDL2 with  Visual Studio 2015 like the google said.

And finally I compiled, that's OK, and linked it but pop up a window

[image]

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. I didn't put the .dll into the .exe file. My mistake.